# Convert scala list to json using loop

Tags: json, scala, gson

I tried a lot to convert my scala list to Json using while loop; the code is as follows:

```
 var json = null
 while (list != null) {
   json = new Gson().toJson(list)
 }
```

the `json` variable must be accessed outside of the loop, so I declared  it outside of the loop and initialized with `null`, but the Scala compiler gives me a type mismatch exception...

Comment: You're initializing json to null, and then trying to assign a String value to it. BTW, you probably want to have json be a val and do a conditional initialization rather than use a var.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a while loop to convert a single list to JSON? Until you explain why you need a loop (or, repeated conversions to JSON, more generally speaking), I'd suggest the following trivial snippet:

```
val json = new Gson().toJson(list)
```

Note that I've also changed `var json` to `val json`.

However, if all you want to know is how to get rid of the type mismatch exception, just change:

```
var json = null
```

to

```
var json: String = null
```

or

```
var json: String = _
```

If you don't declare `json` to be of type `String`, Scala will implicitly take it to be (i.e. infer) of type `Null`, and it's not possible to assign values of type `String` to a variable of type `Null`.

Comment: they both most definitely are at least on my computer using Scala 2.10.2.

Answer (score 0):

This function works fine for List and Map both using plain Scala constructs:

```
def toJson(a: Any): String = {
  a match {
    // number
    case m: Number => m.toString
    // string
    case m: String => "\"" + m + "\""
    case m: Map[AnyRef, AnyRef] => {
"{" + (m map { x => val key = x._1; toJson(key) + ": " + toJson(m(key)) } mkString (", ")) + "}"
}

    case l: Seq[AnyRef] => { "[" + (l map (toJson(_)) mkString (",")) + "]" }

    // for anything else: tuple
    case m: Product => toJson(m.productIterator.toList)
    case m: AnyRef => "\"" + m.toString + "\""
  }
}
```

Complete example is located here: https://gist.github.com/tuxdna/7926531